Rss keeps growing with java17, but nmt result didn't grows at all
Recently we are switching from java8 to 17, but with zgc enabled, most of our microservice used more memory and leading to OOM kill by docker.
I investigated into this, and there is some differenice I noticed:

With zgc, the java process tends to use a lot more shared memory because zgc use tmpfs to create the heap when linux kernel version is below 3.17
tmpfs only goes into cache entry of memory.stat, so rss is most composed of off-heap memory.
Some microserivce with heavy load is having a constant grow of rss but nmt result show committed memory don't grow much (nmt committed memory without heap is only about 500MB, but rss grows to 783MB).
There is similar problem like this one.
Our java version is 17.0.7, I didn't find any bugfix from the release notes of newer version of java17.

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
cache 1764929536
rss 821440512  // Don't know why it is so large and keeps growing
rss huge 92274688
shmem 1073741824 // almost consistent of 1024MB heap
mapped file 1014423552
dirty 38055936
writeback O
swap 0
pgpgin 9505349
pgpgout 8896394
pgfault 9380913
pgmajfault 105
inactive anon 994127872
active anon 901025792
inactive file 606601216
active file 84586496
unevictable O
hierarchical memory limit 2621440000
hierarchical memsw limit 2621440000
total cache 1764929536
total rss 821440512
total rss huge 92274688
total shmem 1073741824
total mapped file 1014423552
total dirty 38055936
total writeback o
total swap o
total pgpgin 9505349
total pgpgout 8896394
total pgfault 9380913
total pgmajfault 105
total inactive anon 994127872
total active anon 901025792
total inactive file 606601216
total active file 84586496 
total unevictable o

nmt result:
Native Memory Tracking:
(Omitting categories weighting less than 1KB) 
Total: reserved=59804324KB, committed=1561672KB
malloc: 202620KB #928892
mmap:  reserved=59601704KB, committed=1359052KB

The question is: how is rss growing without nmt reported committed memory grows?

It's turn out it's related to this jdk issue.
Memory is hold by glibc arena.
Running jcmd <pid> System.trim_native_heap released all memory back to os.
Or we can updated to 17.0.9 and add -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:TrimNativeHeapInterval=5000 to let jvm trim glibc heap by itself.
